# Select list of dates from given range in Firebird

Tags: sql, firebird, gaps-and-islands

I'm designing a report that returns PurchaseOrder due in future week.

Query that I've added below returns `PurchaseOrder` due for a particular `Commodity`, `AmountDue` and its `DeliveryDate`.

Obviously it only returns PO_Dates that are in the table. What I want is to also include dates where no PO is expected, i.e. null for those cell.

To me one possibility is to LEFT JOIN the dataset with set of dates of future week on Date column, that will eventually make the result null where no Purchase Order is expected.

In Firebird I don't know how to select list of week long dates and then use it in the join.

```
SELECT
    PURCHASE_ORDER_DET.COMMODITYID AS COM_ID,
    PURCHASE_ORDER_DET.DELIVERYDATE + CAST ('29.12.1899' AS DATE) as DLV_DATE,
    SUM(PURCHASE_ORDER_DET.REQQUANTITY) as DLV_DUE
FROM
    PURCHASE_ORDER_DET
LEFT JOIN PURCHASE_ORDER_HDR on PURCHASE_ORDER_HDR.POH_ID = 
PURCHASE_ORDER_DET.POH_ID
WHERE 
    PURCHASE_ORDER_DET.COMMODITYID = 1
    AND PURCHASE_ORDER_HDR.STATUS in (0,1,2)
    AND PURCHASE_ORDER_DET.DELIVERYDATE + CAST ('30.12.1899' AS TIMESTAMP) >= '3.01.2019'
    AND PURCHASE_ORDER_DET.DELIVERYDATE + CAST ('30.12.1899' AS TIMESTAMP) <= '9.01.2019'
    AND PURCHASE_ORDER_DET.DELETED is NULL
Group by 
    PURCHASE_ORDER_DET.COMMODITYID,
    PURCHASE_ORDER_DET.DELIVERYDATE
```

**DataSet**

```
COM_ID    DLV_DATE       DLV_DUE    
1         3.01.2019     50.000000
1         5.01.2019     10.000000
```

**Expected**

```
COM_ID    DLV_DATE       DLV_DUE    
1         3.01.2019     50.000000
1         4.01.2019     null
1         5.01.2019     10.000000
1         6.01.2019     null
1         7.01.2019     null
1         8.01.2019     null
1         9.01.2019     null
```

Comment: _"I don't know how to select list of week long dates"_, what do you mean with _week long dates"_? Does that have to do with the fact you also need to do `PURCHASE_ORDER_DET.DELIVERYDATE + CAST ('30.12.1899' AS TIMESTAMP)`? Why aren't you using `DATE` for that `DELIVERYDATE` column?

Comment: BTW: Small tip, instead of `CAST ('30.12.1899' AS TIMESTAMP)`, you could also do `timestamp'1899-12-30', although in the context used, `date'1899-12-30' would be better because you don't actually need a timestamp here and date should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks @MarkRotteveel . 
*"Why aren't you using DATE for that DELIVERYDATE column?"* Yes, it is an odd way but working on exiting system in Production for number of sites. can't change it for now.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel *"date'1899-12-30' would be better"* whilst struggling with dates conversion i've tried `PO.DELIVERYDATE + CAST ('30.12.1899' AS date)` and the one You suggested `date'1899-12-30' + PO.DELIVERYDATE`, both does spit out dates but INCORRECT if timestamp of casting date is greater than afternoon time `12pm`, then the date it give is one day ahead. i.e if timestamp is `09.01.2019, 12:20:54.000` then these two conversion gives `10.01.2019` which is wrong. Don't know how should i carter that. I will post this question separately. I thought should let you know. Thanks again.

Comment: My assumption was based on the query as shown which suggests you need dates only. I'm not sure what you mean with _"if timestamp of casting date is greater than afternoon time 12pm,"_, but either you need to make sure you use dates everywhere, or keep using timestamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring your odd use of datatypes*, there are several possible solutions:

1. Use a 'calendar' table that contains dates, and right join to that table (or left join from that table). The downside of course is having to populate this table (but that is a one-off cost).
2. Use a selectable stored procedure to generate a date range and join on that.
3. Generate the range in a recursive common table expression in the query itself

Option 1 is pretty self-explanatory.

Option 2 would look something like:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE date_range(startdate date, enddate date)
  RETURNS (dateval date)
AS
BEGIN
    dateval = startdate;
    while (dateval <= enddate) do
    BEGIN
       suspend;
       dateval = dateval + 1;
    END
END
```

And then use this in your query like:

```
select date_range.dateval, ...
from date_range(date'2019-01-03', date'2019-01-09') -- use date_range(?, ?) for parameters
left join ...
  on date_range.dateval = ...
```

Option 3 would look something like:

```
WITH RECURSIVE date_range AS (
    SELECT date'2019-01-03' dateval  -- start date, use cast(? as date) if you need a parameter
    FROM rdb$database
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT dateval + 1
    FROM date_range
    WHERE dateval < date'2019-01-09' -- end date use ? if you need a parameter
)
SELECT *
FROM date_range
LEFT JOIN ... 
  ON date_range.dateval = ...
```

Recursive common table expressions have a maximum recursion depth of 1024, which means that it isn't suitable if you need a span wider than 1024 days.

---

*: I'd suggest that you start using `DATE` instead of what looks like the number of days since 30-12-1899. That avoids having to do awkward calculations like you do now. If you do need those number of days, then you can for example use `datediff(DAY FROM date'1899-12-30' TO somedatevalue)` or `somedatevalue - date'1899-12-30'` to convert from date to that numeric value.

Comment: I've opted to go ahead with Stored Procedure. +1 for the possible solutions. Thanks.